Maximal abelian algebras and type I factors
Let $\mathcal{A}$  be a maximal abelian von Neumann algebra of a type I factor $\mathcal{N\subseteq B}(\mathcal{H})$ where $\mathcal{H}$ is a separable Hilbert space. We assume that $\mathcal{N}$ has a cyclic vector. Is $\mathcal{A}$ maximal abelian for $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$?

This isn’t even true in finite dimensions. For example, for any $n \geq 2$, $M_n(\mathbb{C}) = M_n(\mathbb{C}) \otimes 1 \subset B(\mathbb{C}^n \otimes \mathbb{C}^n)$ is a type I factor with a cyclic vector $\sum_{i=1}^n e_i \otimes e_i$. But $l_\infty^n \subset M_n(\mathbb{C})$, while being maximally abelian in $M_n(\mathbb{C})$, is certainly not maximally abelian in $B(\mathbb{C}^n \otimes \mathbb{C}^n)$. (Indeed, $l_\infty^n \otimes l_\infty^n$ is abelian and properly contains $l_\infty^n \otimes 1$.)
(If you want an infinite-dimensional example, the same example works by replacing $n$ with $\infty$ - the only subtlety is the existence of a cyclic vector, which now can be given by $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^i}e_i \otimes e_i$.)
